# Javascript async call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am having trouble with Javascript async call. The Car class below has a **move** function which takes two arguments, the first one is a value, the second one is a call back function, which will be called after 1 second, and this callback function takes the value returned by **forward** method.

```
var Car = function() {
  this._count = 0;
};

Car.prototype = {
  move: function(value, onMoved) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      onMoved(this.forward(value));
    }.bind(this), 1000);
  },
  forward: function(value) {
    this._count = this._count + value;
    return this._count;
  }
};
```

I want to call the move function like this:

```
var values = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var car = new Car();

values.forEach(function(value) {
  car.move(value, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Now my problem is the call back function **onMoved** does not wait for 1 second to execute between each value that it is outputting. How can I make it so it wait between each value that it is outputting? I am allowed to use underscore.js. Thanks.

Comment: "does not wait for 1 second to execute" — Yes, it does.

Comment: Are you asking how to make it wait **between** each value that it is outputting? At the moment it is waiting for one second after you run your (entire) forEach loop.

Comment: @Quentin, yes, you are right, I modified my question.

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout in javascript registers callback function in a queue to execute in future once the current execution stack is free. for example:-

```
while(1){
 setTimeout(function(){
   console.log('hello');
 },1000);
}
```

this will not print hello as the execution stack will never be free.

Coming back to the example we call move method which will be pushed to a queue. After one second it starts executing each function one by one without any delay as the setTimeout is set to a fixed time ie. 1000 millisecond.

workaround:-

```
var Car = function() {
  this._count = 0;
};

Car.statCount = 0;

Car.prototype = {
 move: function(value, onMoved) {
  this.constructor.statCount++;
  setTimeout(function() {
    onMoved(this.forward(value));
  }.bind(this), 1000*Car.statCount);
 },
 forward: function(value) {
   this._count = this._count + value;
   return this._count;
 },
 constructor: Car
};


var values = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var car = new Car();

values.forEach(function(value) {
  car.move(value, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This works great. Is it possible to stop the timer if result in the callback function contains errors?

Comment: if you need more control over it then use a register method to store all and start move once all are registered. Please find the link where i have modified the example
[link](http://jsbin.com/xaqavexilo/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a 1 sec. wait between each call, you might consider using the `setInterval` method on window, instead of utilizing the setTimeout method:

You could add some method performing some actions for each iteration, and finish iterating when all values are processed:

```
var i=0;
function go(result) { 
    if (!!values[i]) {
        car.move(values[i], function(result) {console.log(result);})
        i++;
    } else {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
```

And call this function using `setInterval`

```
var interval = window.setInterval(go, 1000);
```

Have a look at the following fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/adw1k98m/1/

(see console log for output)